# How to access iis server on Windows XP from MAC 10.5

Tags: objective-c, xcode

For my application i need to access data from a local server(IIS) which is on windows XP over the network.
In my code am using reachability and giving host name as

```
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@""];
```

How can i do this.Please help me.

Comment: Please describe your problem. What challenges, specifically, are you having?

Comment: What type of data? IIS metadata or web application hosted in IIS?

Comment: I need to access a database located on the Win Xp machine.
Initially, my code has a web address where the database was located and I use to do all the DB operations linked to that web address.
Now I need access to the local server, and not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the "Reachability" class from [Apple's Reachability sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability), you need to specify the host name you're trying to reach, like `[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"]`

Comment: i am trying to access a local server (located on Win XP IIS). what need to be entered instead of www.apple.com.
For example, the IP address of my local server is 192.168.2.16. Please help me accessing the files on that local server.

Comment: Enter the hostname of the server you're trying to reach. The "Reachability" class may also support entering the numeric IP address; not sure about that